# Pressing Super key always shows shortcut keys

Tags: 12.04, unity, shortcut-keys

When I simply press (not hold) <kbd>Super</kbd> I always see the shortcuts list. And after I release the button it stays on my screen. Normally pressing Super leads to Dash opening and to view the shortcuts list I need to hold <kbd>Super</kbd>. So to open the Dash I need press <kbd>Super</kbd> twice. I have ThinkPad T520i. I tried to disable shortcut list, but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Does it do it with a very quick tap?

Comment: Are You sure that Superkey on keyboard isn't somehow stuck when You press it?

Comment: I tried to press it million times in very different ways)) I gues I become like Flash soon)) the problem is not in my slowliness, the problem is somewhere in machine. Btw I have few virtual machines on other computers and everything works perfect there, so I know how it should really work.

Comment: @James see above

Comment: @zuberuber see above

Comment: Artem, just trying to narrow down the problem, not questioning your abilities. Anyway, any custom shortcuts defined under System Settings/Keyboard/Shortcuts?

Comment: @James no custom shortcuts

Comment: The same thing happens when I try to open HUD. When I press it for the first time nothing happens. Only when I press it second time HUD opens.

Comment: One more issue to add. I can't copy/paste in terminal using Ctrl+Shift+C/V. It simply doesn't work, however the shortcuts set by default in terminal.

Comment: @James I've found the solution. Check the problem description update. Thank you for trying to help me)

Comment: @Artem I am glad you found the solution. Can you add it as an answer instead of editing the question? Thanks.

Comment: @Artem Glad to hear you figured it out. You need to accept as the answer the solution you posted. You going through this may help someone else in the future who has the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I finally found out the solution. The problem was I turned ON "Sticky keys" switcher, so I simply turned it OFF and everything works great now.
>
> [*Artem*](https://askubuntu.com/users/79877/artem)

For reference, the Sticky Keys option is in the *Typing* tab of Universal Access in System Settings.